# Proving that if $a,b > 1$, then $5^a - 3^b=16$ has only one solution with $a=2$ and $b=2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

This may be one of those problems that is easy to state but very hard to prove.  I don't know.

I have tried to show that there is only one solution but I have not made much progress.

Here's what I have:

If there exists $a,b > 2$, then:

$$5^2(5^{a-2} - 1) = 3^2(3^{b-2}-1)$$

$a-2 = u(3-1)(3) = 6u$ where $u \ge 1$

$b-2 = v(5-1)(5) = 20v$ where $v \ge 1$

So, as I understand it, the problem comes down to showing that for all $u,v$:

$$5^2(2)(1 + 5 + 5^2 + \cdots + 5^{6u-1}) \ne 3^2(1 + 3 + 3^2 + \cdots + 3^{20v-1})$$

I can't figure out any step after this.  Is my thinking wrong?  Is there $a,b > 2$ where $5^a - 3^b = 16$

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: I would try to prove that both $a,b$ must be even. Then I would try factorizing it into $(5^x + 3^y)(5^x - 3^y) = 2^4$.

Comment: @YiyuanLee Beat me to it. : – /

Comment: Thanks, @Yiyuan.  I missed that.  Good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider everything modulo $3$. Then,

$$(-1)^a \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

From this, $a$ must be even, i.e. $a = 2m$ for some integer $m \ge 1$.

Now, consider everything modulo $5$. Then,

$$-(-2)^b \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$

From this (why?), $b$ must even, i.e. $b = 2n$ for some $n \ge 1$.

So we rewrite:

$$5^{2m} - 3^{2n} = 16$$
$$(5^m - 3^{n})(5^m + 3^{n}) = 2^4$$

Now, let $5^m - 3^{n} = 2^x$ and $5^m + 3^{n} = 2^{x + k}$ for some integers $x,k \ge 0$ s.t. $2x + k = 4$. Then, adding both up,

$$2\cdot5^m = 2^x + 2^{x + k} = 2^x(1 + 2^k)$$
$$5^m = 2^{x - 1}(1 + 2^k)$$

But if $x - 1 > 0$, then both sides will be even, which is false since $5^m$ is odd. So $x - 1 = 0 \implies x = 1 \implies k = 4 - 2 = 2$. Therefore, we have

$$5^m - 3^{n} = 2$$
$$5^m + 3^{n} = 8$$

The rest is trivial (Hint: sum up both, or subtract one from another).

Comment: Possible typo. You write $b^{4n}$. Should that be $3^{4n}$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Thanks! That was embarrassing..

Comment: Happens to all of us. :) Good answer though, +1. The other answer has a flaw. I don't see why it is accepted.

Comment: @Sabyasachi, I agree.  I've accepted Yiyuan's answer.  Thanks, Yiyuan!  Very clear.

Answer (score 4):

Observing the equation modulo $5$ and $3$, you know $a$, $b$ to be even, say $a = 2m$, $b = 2n$. Then $5^{2m} - 3^{2n} = (5^m - 3^n)(5^m + 3^n)$. Both factors have to be positive integers if they multiply up to $16$.

Comment: **Positive** doesn't prove anything. I am pretty sure $5^{1000}-3^{1000}$ is positive as well.

Comment: Thanks, @k.stm, very clear.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I didn’t meant that comment to be final blow to the proof, but it’s unnecessary/misleading, so I’ll remove/replace it. (I was thinking it’ll be easier to think about it as factorization of positive integers, but I should have stressed the integer-part instead, yeah.)

Comment: @k.stm Yeah better now. Upvoted.